# How to add city (not state!) in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-address, dropdown-attribute, address

How can I add cities in city field in address form of magento in checkout?

I want add city not state, want load it auto same as state

State load drop-down after select country, now want city drop-down after select state